# Playing a standard/system sound on phone xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there a standard cross platform way of playing a 250 ms or so 'ding' on Xamarin Forms iOS and Android?

Mark Wardell

Comment: Hi , you can use Dependecy Service for each platform to implement that .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use **[DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/registration-and-resolution)** to play default system notification sound in each platform .

Create **IPlaySoundService** Interface :

```
public interface IPlaySoundService 
{
    void PlaySystemSound();
}
```

Implement the `PlaySystemSound` method in **iOS** as follow:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(PlaySoundService))]
namespace AppCarouselViewSample.iOS
{
    public class PlaySoundService : IPlaySoundService
    {
        public void PlaySystemSound()
        {    
            var sound = new SystemSound(1000);
            sound.PlaySystemSound();
        }
    }
}
```

Implement the `PlaySystemSound` method in **Android** as follow :

```
[assembly:Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(PlaySoundService))]
namespace AppCarouselViewSample.Droid
{
    public class PlaySoundService : IPlaySoundService
    {
        public void PlaySystemSound()
        {
            Android.Net.Uri uri = RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Ringtone);
            Ringtone rt = RingtoneManager.GetRingtone(MainActivity.instance.ApplicationContext, uri);
            rt.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the definition of `instance` from **MainActivity** :

```
namespace xxx.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "AppCarouselViewSample", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        public static MainActivity instance { set; get; }
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            instance = this;

            Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags(new string[] { "CarouselView_Experimental", "SwipeView_Experimental", "IndicatorView_Experimental" });
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());


        }
...
}
```

Then it they will play the default notification Sound in each platform . You can modify `SystemSoundID` in iOS to fit your wants .Here is [the Sound ID list](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/AudioServices) .

Comment: Thanks i will test and mark as answered if it works

Comment: @MarkWardell I also update the sound id list in answer , you can have a check that which one is your needed .

Comment: I have the ios Compiled aok my MainActivity did not go so well

Comment: Jiang  iOS was awesome... Android did not exactly compile.... Then I fot creative here and it blows up. But I can take from here...

Comment: Okey , you can create a static parameter(`instance`) in `MainActivity` , then can use it in `PlaySoundService` . I have updated answer .

Comment: the type or namespace "SystemSound" cannot be found. How to use this class?

Answer (score 0):

here is my now compiling yet crashing Droid implementation

using Android.Media;
using TripCalculator.Droid.Services;

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(PlaySoundService))]
// Crashes
namespace TripCalculator.Droid.Services
{
    public class PlaySoundService : IPlaySoundService
    {
        public void PlaySystemSound()
        {
            var currentContext = Android.App.Application.Context;
            Android.Net.Uri uri = RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Ringtone);

            Ringtone rt = RingtoneManager.GetRingtone(currentContext.ApplicationContext, uri);
            rt.Play();
        }
    }
}
```