# How to play a simple beep on Android with .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, android, .net, maui

I want to write a Morse code training app that uses a system beep instead of an audio file.

How can I make the app play a simple beep.

Also, need to control the duration.

Thanks,
Terry

I tried the RingtoneManager but did not get the results I need. Perhaps I am just using it wrong. I used this code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77945442/net-maui-play-default-notification-sound-beep-android) on stackoverflow.

```
private void PlayBeepBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    #if ANDROID

    var instance = Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Platform.CurrentActivity;
    Android.Net.Uri uri = RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification);
    Ringtone rt = RingtoneManager.GetRingtone(instance.ApplicationContext, uri);
    rt.Play();

    #endif
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61300062/playing-a-standard-system-sound-on-phone-xamarin-forms

Comment: I tested the code and it works well. Which part did you have the issue with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write a demo by using the button. I use the timer to control the time, it starts when you press the button and it stop when you release the button.

Here is the code you can refer to:

In the Mainpage.xaml.

```
 <VerticalStackLayout>
    
     <Button Text="Click this button to start"  Pressed="Button_Pressed" Released="Button_Released" ></Button>

     <Label x:Name="label"
            Text="Press and hold the Button above"
            FontSize="18"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
 </VerticalStackLayout>
```

Here is the code behind in the MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class SignOut : ContentPage
{

    IDispatcherTimer timer;
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    public SignOut()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        timer = Dispatcher.CreateTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
        timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            label.Rotation = 360 * (stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds % 1);

            var instance = Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Platform.CurrentActivity;
            Android.Net.Uri uri = RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification);
            Ringtone rt = RingtoneManager.GetRingtone(instance.ApplicationContext, uri);
            rt.Play();
        };
    }

    private void Button_Pressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        stopwatch.Start();
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void Button_Released(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stopwatch.Stop();
        timer.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: As it turns out, my VS install is screwed up. After I get it straitened out, I'll re-visit this.